# javascript toggle button to open and close a div

Tags: javascript, button, html, toggle

How can I get my toggle button to not only change names from view to hide but to also display a table that I have in a div tag?

I currently have the following for my script:

```
   <script type = "text/javascript">
function buttonToggle(where,pval,nval)
{
        where.value = (where.value == pval) ? nval : pval;

}
</script>
```

and this is the code for the button:

```
<input type="button" name="button1" id="nextbt" value="View " onclick="buttonToggle(this,'View ','Hide ')">
```

Comment: Can you explain more in depth what you want to accomplish? maybe an example?

Comment: when the page is loaded the button would say view and the table would be hidden in a div. when the button is clicked it would switch to hide and the table would be shown. when hide is clicked the table would go away and the button would go back to view

Answer (score 4):

Well if you can use jQuery it would be very easy:

```
$('#nextbt').click(function() {
    if ($(this).attr('value') == 'show') {
        $(this).attr('value', 'hide');
        $('#myotherdiv').slideDown();
    } else {
        $(this).attr('value', 'show');
        $('#myotherdiv').slideUp();
    }

    // or if you don't care about changing the button text, simply:
    $('#myotherdiv').slideToggle();
});
```

More here: http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/

Comment: It is also pretty easy without jQuery ;)

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
function buttonToggle(where,pval,nval) {
    var display =  where.value === nval ? 'none' : 'block'; // or 'table'
    document.getElementById('yourTableId').style.display = display;
    where.value = (where.value == pval) ? nval : pval;
}
```

---

Or better:

```
function buttonToggle(source, target, show_val, hide_val) {
    var display =  source.value === hide_val ? 'none' : 'block'; // or 'table'
    target.style.display = display;
    source.value = (source.value == show_val) ? hide_val : show_val;
}
```

and instead of adding your click handler inline, use JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById('nextbt').onclick = (function() {
    var table = document.getElementById('yourTableId');
    return function() {
        buttonToggle(this, table, 'View', 'Hide');
    };
}());
```

Comment: Just a note - the final code block uses 'toggleButton'.  This should be 'buttonToggle' in case anyone wonders.

Answer (score 1):

use jQuery. see demo http://jsfiddle.net/nBJXq/2/

Comment: Apart from that it was not asked for jQuery, you could at least post your code in your answer. Otherwise it is a pretty poor answer.

Comment: @Felix Kling, What makes my answer poor? Even if jQuery was not asked we should recommend using it. If the asker has mentioned "No jQuery" i wouldn't have even attempted this answer. try to give more.

Comment: What if your link breaks in the future for whatever reason? The answer itself without the link is not every helpful. And don't take for granted that the link will always work.

Comment: @Felix Kling, My Point is Use jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you add the `id` of the table you want to show/hide as the `rel` attribute of the button:

```
<input type="button" name="button1" id="nextbt" 
       rel="myTable" value="View " 
       onclick="buttonToggle(this,'View ','Hide ')">

<table id="myTable">
    <tr>
        <td>myTable</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Then you could add the following to your `buttonToggle` function:

```
function buttonToggle(where, pval, nval) {
    var table = document.getElementById(where.attributes.rel.value);
    where.value = (where.value == pval) ? nval : pval;
    table.style.display = (table.style.display == 'block') ? 'none' : 'block';
}
```

[See example.](http://jsfiddle.net/qMEzn/2/)

Answer (score 0):

You will want to change the div's `style.visible` to `visible` or `hidden`, and/or set the `style.display` to `block` or `none`.

See: http://w3schools.com/css/css_display_visibility.asp

Comment: Shouldn't the `display` property be set to `table` instead of `block` since it's a table?

Comment: @Rfvgyhn: The `display` property deals with how the div is rendered, and it does not care what is contained within it. `display` can be set to `block`, `inline`, or `none`. There is no `table`.

Comment: There is: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/display But I don't think that it makes a big difference.

Comment: Ah, I was thinking he was modifying the table and not the parent div. I guess I missed where you said div too. I'll figure out this reading thing one of these days.